# SQL Injection on POST JSON request

Tags: sql-injection, burp-suite, json

I have a web application vulnerable to SQL injections. I'm using BurpSuite to intercept the requests. More specifically, the data variable below is vulnerable. I added my own data to aggregates and filters:

```
data=[{
   "params": {
     "dsreq": "{
         \"version\":1,
         \"type\":\"SQL\",
         \"limit\":500, 
         \"aggregates\":[
             {\"expr\":\"user()\"}
         ],
         \"partitions\":[],
         \"filters\":[\" 1=1 --\"],
         \"having\":[],
         \"dataset_id\":3}"
         }
     }
   ]
```

This payload returns the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 'portal' user() FROM active_tab tab_0 WHERE (TRUE) AND ((TA_0.grp_id) = 'sqlgrp1')
```

The aggregates key in JSON corresponds to the columns section of the SQL statement and the filters corresponds to the condition.

This does fetch some data from the DB, but it only returns data from my group. Notice how the where clause includes 'TRUE' (my 1=1 statement), but then the application appended parenthesis around it and an additional AND statement. 
My goal is to get around that so I can get data from all groups. My group id is sqlgrp1.

How can I trick the filter to stop executing the WHERE clause after the TRUE condition or not even execute the WHERE clause at all? Where condition is added if filters key is left empty.

Comment: You assertion is wrong. There is no software that will evaluate 1=1 as true. And as you have a comment operator in the payload which nowhere can be seen in the query, I doubt this code is vulnerable at all. Or you must provide a more convincing evidence.

Comment: When I add this to the filter value: \"filters\":[\" TA_0.`grp_id`='sndgrp' -- \"] the new SQL statement is SELECT 'portal' user() FROM active_tab tab_0 WHERE ((TA_0.grp_id) = 'sndgrp') AND ((TA_0.grp_id) = 'sqlgrp1')

Answer (score 3):

I'm really just reiterating what @YourCommonSense said in a comment, but anyway:

There's nothing here to suggest that there is an SQLi vulnerability.  I've built systems like this that operate very similarly: they have a very expressive JSON input that allows the client to have more-fine grained control over their query.  This can be advantageous because it gives the client more control without having to adjust the server for every single use-case.  This definitely *doesn't* mean that there is an SQLi vulnerability.  As a for instance, in my systems each API endpoint (in this case the `dataset` might be the equivalent) is explicitly tied to a table and additional server-side-specified conditions that are *always* added to the query.  Any additional filters passed up by the client are explicitly joined in with the `AND` operator while the `OR` operator cannot be used at all.  Further, all client side conditions are explicitly white-listed: the client is only allowed to filter by a pre-defined list of columns and specifying the operator is not allowed: only the search value can be specified (the column itself explicitly determines what operator is used in the actual query).  Finally everything is built into a query that uses prepared queries for the actual execution.  All of this makes it just about impossible to have an SQLi vulnerability, while still allowing the client more fine-grained control over the actual API results.  I mention this not to talk about my system, but because what I built looks almost exactly like what you have, and the results you show are exactly what you would see with my system as well.  In particular:

1. You seem to have concluded that the `WHERE (true)` part of that query is the result of your `1=1` injection.  This is most likely not the case.  Making a parser recognize the `1=1` condition and auto translate that to `true` would be a lot of work and makes no sense - something like `1=1` would only show up due to SQLi, so I can't imagine this would be the desired behavior of any system.  Best guess is that the (true) part is added automatically to the query in all cases to make it easier to build the query (you don't have to keep track of whether or not you already had a condition and therefore whether or not you have to put `AND` in front of the condition you are adding on) and b) MySQL will ignore it anyway when it builds the query plan, so it will have almost zero impact on performance.
2. The fact that your comment didn't show up in the final query suggests that the system has parsed your condition and completely rejected it.  Again, your condition is obviously being processed by the system and not just being added straight on the end (hence why your comment is not in the final query), and there would be no reason for a parser to recognize your comment and remove it - those only show up due to SQLi vulnerabilities, so any system smart enough to parse a comment and remove it should (theoretically) be smart enough to recognize the SQLi danger and reject the request all together.
3. The condition on `grp_id` is there even though you didn't specify it.  This is likely a sign that this particular API end point (or `dataset_id`?) automatically adds in conditions that you will not be able to remove.
4. It does *look* like you got `user()` in the select, but it's hard to tell what (if anything) the significance of that fact is.

So I would say that without more details there isn't much to go on, but this doesn't look especially vulnerable from here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of `filters` is directly spliced into the SQL statement after `(TRUE` - i.e. before the closing bracket....

```
\"filters\":[\" 1=1 --\ ) UNION SELECT 'portal' user() FROM active_tab tab_0 WHERE ("],
```

Would reveal all the groups. If it is being spliced somewhere else, the brackets may need to be moved around a bit. But the absence of the value in your example JSON-in-JSON from your example SQL, and the lack of any additional examples casts a lot of doubt on this.

Answer (score 0):

The malicious request should be prevented to reach at persistence layer of your web application. You must apply the following to protect your application from malicious data coming external sources.

- JSON sanitation at controller level.
- Input validation for each JSON object.
- Whitelisting for sensitive parameters (especially the filter! you cannot do 1=1 to reach at persistence layer).

The listed 3 are just the minimum protection that MUST be applied to any web application. Take note you are not only vulnerable to SQL injection but instead you are also vulnerable from cross site scripting. I would suggest you read the OWASP cheat sheet and OWASP developers guide to do proper coding with security in place. See below link.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet